# Magento 2 Get sub category of parent by object Manager in phtml

Tags: magento2

I want to get the sub category objects of parent category.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');

$parent_category_id = 6; //Parent category ID
$categoryObj = $categoryRepository->get($parent_category_id);
$subcategories = $categoryObj->getChildrenCategories();
foreach($subcategories as $subcategorie) {
    echo '    --> '.$subcategorie->getName().'';
}
```